# Altering column on two tables simultaneously

Tags: sql, alter

I have linked tables, `players` and `playerRegSeason`. They are  linked by a `playerID` which is the primary key for `players` and is in a strange non-numerical form. I want to make it so all new entries have unique auto incremented `playerID`s. If I alter the column to be auto incrementing it changes all the current `playerID`s, which I'd be ok with, but I lose the relationsihp to the `playerRegSeason`. Is there a way to alter the `playerID` column so it will automatically update in `playerRegSeason`?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Why not create a new column called intID. Then have the id created using the autoincrementer. Example right now playerID is ABC1234. You can keep all the existing ID's since they already exist. In your code you can basically say that playerID for the new person is ABC + the autoincrementer value. Does that make senses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would be better off doing it in stages.

1. Create a new column with the auto-increment to the `players` table and populate it.
2. Add column to the `playerRegSeason` allow it to be `NULL` initially
3. Update the new column in `playerRegSeason` to point to the new `playerID` column.
4. Alter the column in `playerRegSeason` to not allow nulls
5. Add a new foreign constraint to `playerRegSeason`
6. Drop the old foreign constraint
7. Drop the old ID & foreign fields from both tables.

EDIT:
Elaboration of step 3 as requested

```
UPDATE playerRegSeason s
INNER JOIN players p ON s.playerID = p.playerID
SET s.NewPlayerID =  p.NewPlayerID
```

However the exact syntax may vary depending on the version of SQL

Comment: sorry, but could you elaborate on step 3?

Comment: No problem, I have added that to the answer.